# SysV init scripts to systemd migration in RHEL7

Tags: linux, rhel, systemd, sysvinit

Please find the Sys V Init scripts for (User processes)Agent and Security daemon in Linux.

1. Agent Daemon startup script
   /etc/rc.d/init.d/Agentdaemon
   /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S91Agentdaemon
2. Security Daemon startup script
   /etc/rc.d/init.d/Securitydaemon
   /etc/rc.d/rc5.d/S91Securitydaemon

Let us assume both agent and securiy daemons need a common parent say common agent. If common agent is not started at the time of reboot, any of the other daemons will start common agent and the other daemon will 
skip to start the common agent. There is 'ps' command check to see if common agent is running or not to skip creation in both the Agentdaemon and Securitydaemon scripts.
This has worked fine in RHEL 6.2. But in RHEL 7, I am seeing two common agents are running.

And also I doubt that systemd has started both agent and security daemon parallely. Somehow 'ps' has not shown the common agent running.

Ex: ps -ef | grep common | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' is not showing the common process started by other script and hence the other script also starts the common agent.

Is there any way I can avoid the startup scripts run in parrallel or Should I migrate the scripts to systemd format? 
Quick workaround is more interested than migrating all the scripts from Sys V init type to systemd.

Comment: The quick workaround is stop running the agent and security daemon from `systemd` by disabling their unit files and use the old approach to start the daemons.

Comment: You need to re-read the question, Thushi.  The questioner _is using_ the old approach to starting the the daemons; it isn't working (because of one of the many well-known problems with `rc` scripts); and the questioner has asked about using systemd unit files instead.

Comment: We do not want the customer to go and kill process on each machine(where the agents will be deployed on lot of machines). Anyhow Thank you Thushi and JdeBP

Answer (score 2):

> Should I migrate the scripts to systemd format?

Yes.

You're being bitten by a well-known flaw in System 5 `rc` scripts.  It's not really anything to do with systemd.  You could have hit the flaw if you'd managed to start the scripts up in parallel some other way, such as with `startpar` for example.

It's well known that grepping the output of `ps` is prone to races, both against `grep` and against ongoing system state, and one can find  *decades* of people reporting hitting these same faults over and over again with different shell scripts.  It's daft and wrongheaded, and mentioned in the "BUGS" section of the BSD manual page for `ps`.  The world should know better by now.

The world does know better, and has for some time.  We've had service managers that work properly, without all of these bodged-together mechanisms involving grepping the process list and files that may or may not contain the right number, since the early 1990s.  You should *definitely*, if you are being hit by this and other race conditions, throw those rickety, failure-prone, idiosyncratic, and messy System 5 `rc` scripts away and use proper service management.  No ifs; no buts; no  "quick workarounds" bodges upon the bodges that you are already using (the extra `grep`s being themselves a bodge in the first place).

There are many such service managers available.  You don't *have* to use systemd.  The various scripts that one would write for runit, nosh, or perp are as simple as the unit files that one would write for systemd.

In the nosh and systemd way of doing things, you don't have the two primary services checking for and running the secondary one.  That's the job of the service management system.  Rather you simply *declare a dependency* from the two primary services upon the secondary one, so that the service management system knows that when it is told to start `Agentdaemon.service` and `Securitydaemon.service` it has to start `common.service` as well.  In systemd service units this would be a `Requires=` or a `Wants=` setting.

## Further reading

- Shlomi Noach
  (2009-10-01).  [*How NOT to test that mysqld is alive*](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/how-not-to-test-that-mysqld-is-alive).  code.openark.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*The daemontools family*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/daemontools-family.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [*A side-by-side look at run scripts and service units.*](https://jdebp.eu./FGA/run-scripts-and-service-units-side-by-side.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemd.unit`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- Greg Wooledge.  ["The risk of parsing the process tree"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#The_risk_of_parsing_the_process_tree). *Process Management*.  Greg's Wiki.