# systemd custom status message?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to write a systemd service which should expose the options `start|stop|status|restart`.

This is the current script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Daemon to start ark server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/arkdaemon start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/arkdaemon stop
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I can't find any way to specify a custom status command.
Is there a way I think, but how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Systemd support custom status message, but here are some prerequsites that must be met:

- type of service should be `notify`
- your service must update systemd with your current service status either via `/run/systemd/notify` socket or by calling systemd-notify

As a reference you can check Apache HTTPD on Fedora (maybe same in other distros, don't know):

```
systemctl status httpd.service


● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server    
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-10-06 15:21:07 CEST; 18h ago
  Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 14424 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  
  Main PID: 4105 (httpd)
  Status: "Total requests: 8; Idle/Busy workers 100/0;Requests/sec: 0.000118; Bytes served/sec:   0 B/sec"
```

You can see that Apache is reporting status as **Total requests: 8; Idle/Busy workers 100/0**

So when I attached `strace` on pid 4105, we can see that it is periodicaly sending status updates to `systemd`:

```
sudo strace -f -p 4105

wait4(-1, 0x7ffcfab4a25c, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}) = 0 (Timeout)
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0) = 8
getsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, [212992], [4]) = 0
setsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUFFORCE, [8388608], 4) = 0
sendmsg(8, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/systemd/notify"}, msg_namelen=21, msg_iov=[{iov_base="READY=1\nSTATUS=Total requests: 8"..., iov_len=110}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 110
close(8)                                = 0
wait4(-1, 0x7ffcfab4a25c, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED, NULL) = 0
```

You can see that it is sending **READY=1\nSTATUS=Total requests: 8...** into socket `/run/systemd/notify`

Recommended reading

`man systemd-notify`

or [official documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-notify.html).

Example : [Service startup in Systemd](https://zerokspot.com/weblog/2016/11/06/systemd-service-startup/)

Answer (score 10):

> I'm trying to write a systemd service which should expose the options `start|stop|status|restart`.

Your first mistake.  Service units are not scripts.  They don't *have* options.  The options are to the `systemctl` command, and they are uniform across all units.

> I realize using centos seems to be non-standard,

Your second mistake, related to your third mistake:

> [I'm going to merge a PR to fix the lot of stuff in debian/ubuntu. then we'll have to write an alternative daemon for centos, because it uses a different init method.](https://github.com/FezVrasta/ark-server-tools/issues/27#issuecomment-113826494)

CentOS is *not* the odd one out.  Ubuntu version 15, Debian 8, and CentOS 7 all use systemd and all need a proper systemd service unit.

```
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/arkdaemon start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/arkdaemon stop
```

Your fourth mistake.  You don't write service units by punting everything over to a System 5 `rc` script.  Aside from the fact that that won't work on Debian and Ubuntu, because they try to punt everything *back* to the service unit; it's a horror of a concept, worthy of an entry in the systemd house of horror.  Looking at the System 5 `rc` script, it puts back in all of the wrongheaded nonsense — racy grepping the output of `ps`, wrongheaded use of `sudo` to *drop* privileges (rather than *acquire* them) — that switching to a proper service manager gets rid of.

Don't muddle around at random.  *Understand how your dæmon is actually run*, and then write a service unit that describes that.

Your System 5 `rc` script calls a program named `arkmanager` with `start` and `stop` verbs.  So at first blush one might think that a systemd service unit should too.  But it turns out that `arkmanager` *itself* is *yet another* Poor Man's Dæmon Supervisor written (badly, as they always are) in shell script, that does all of the same nonsense and much more — grepping the output of `ps`, using `screen` (sic!) as a way to fork off a process and later send a `SIGINT` to it, maintaining its own (non-rotated) log file, and using hardwired CSI sequences (sic!) in a program that when managing a dæmon isn't being run connected to a terminal in the first place.

You are busily constructing another horror.  Stop.

Stripping away the horrendous tottering edifice that has one Poor Man's Dæmon Supervisor supervising another, which is in turn abusing `screen` as a third ad hoc supervisor, one finds that the underlying service management actually looks something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=ARK server
Documentation=https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212059/
After=network.target

[Service]
User=steam
Environment=SESSION=YourLinuxSessionName
Environment=QUERYPORT=27016
Environment=PASS=password
Environment=ADMINPASS=adminpassword
ExecStart=/home/steam/ARK/ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/ShooterGameServer TheIsland?SessionName=${SESSION}?QueryPort=${QUERYPORT}?ServerPassword=${PASS}?ServerAdminPassword=${ADMINPASS}?listen
LimitNOFILE=100000
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And what's the first rule of migrating to systemd?  That's right.  It's now 2015, and someone has most likely already done it.  And indeed here, someone already has, beating me by 4 days.  They didn't construct a horror either.

## Further reading

- Lennart Poettering (2013-10-07).  [`systemctl`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*The systemd House of Horror*](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/).  Frequently Given Answers (URL fixed).
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207363/5132
- https://askubuntu.com/a/626858/43344
- ["Automatic Startup"](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Dedicated_Server_Setup#Automatic_Startup). *Dedicated Server Setup*.  Survival Evolved wiki.

Comment: well actually you have looked at the master branch, we have improved it quite a bit in the 1.1 branch

Comment: "I realize using centos seems to be non-standard," is related to the fact that ARK developers suggest to use Ubuntu 14.04. You talk without knowing the context here.

Comment: "I'm going to merge a PR to fix the lot of stuff in debian/ubuntu. then we'll have to write an alternative daemon for centos, because it uses a different init method." here, I was talking about Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 6.6, and yes, Ubuntu 14.40 uses a different init script then the one of CentOS 6.6

Comment: @JdeBP I do not really like your answer, seems to me quite offensive without a proper answer, which would be in one sentence, that one can call `systemctl status ...` to get the status...