# Alternative to "openvt", but for pseudo terminal (pts). Exists?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, io-redirection, pty

Alternative to "openvt"...but for pseudo terminal(pts)... Exists?

Openvrt operate only tty...but not pts.

(Example: lauch comand in specific pts and with user of shell pts destination)

```
Command <dev pts> <launch_command>
```

Comment: `script`. `script /dev/null`. I don't know of any _readily available_ tool which creates a pty without starting a command in it. Please be more clear about what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ptyrun and ptybandage

There are plenty of readily available tools that do the equivalent of what `openvt` does: open a fresh pseudo-terminal and run a designated command with its standard I/O attached to that pseudo-terminal.

- Daniel J. Bernstein's original `ptyrun` and `ptybandage`
- My `ptyrun` and `ptybandage` build on nosh toolset utilities
- The `zpty` extension module in the Z shell

```
% tty ; ptybandage tty
/dev/pts/5
/dev/pts/6
%
```

Of course, the difference is that in the case of pseudo-terminals, one has to have some process attached to the master side of the pseudo-terminal to actually *do* something with the I/O.  In the case of Bernstein's tools thats the `ptyio` program.  `ptyrun` and `ptybandage` are in fact scripts that devolve into the `ptyget`, `ptyio`, and `ptyspawn` programs.  The case is similar for my tools, where the `pty-run` program is the inner I/O workhorse, combined with `pty-get-tty` and `open-controlling-tty`.

Which means that if one wants more fine-grained operation, just opening the pseudo-terminal master side and then chain loading *something* to do the rest, one can invoke `pty-get-tty` or `ptyget` directly.

## terminal multiplexors

In the case of the terminal multiplexors `tmux` and `screen`, there are of course mechanisms (that are parts of those programs) for starting a new (inner) terminal and running a command attached to it.  See those programs' doco for details.

## existing pseudo-terminals

What these tools (`ptyrun`, `ptybandage`, et al.) do *not* do is run commands attaching them to *existing* pseudo-terminals.  They always create fresh ones.

There's little call for running commands attached to existing pseudo-terminals.  But it can be done.  It can be done with my toolset, for example.  Just set the `TTY` environment variable to the *slave side* device filename of the existing pseudo-terminal, and invoke the command via the `open-controlling-tty` tool.

```
TTY=/dev/pts/5 open-controlling-tty $SHELL
```

This creates contention for the terminal amongst different unrelated concurrent processes, of course, and makes one painfully aware of how much job control shells are doing for one.  ☺

Also note that several SSH servers and terminal emulators will close the master side if *their* slave-side child process exits.

## what all these are not

Finally, note that these are not input-stuffing mechanisms, for driving an existing interactive shell on an existing pseudo-terminal, sending commands to its input.  They all attach *new* processes to (fresh) pseudo-terminals.

But then that is not what `openvt` does, either.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249801/5132
- Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). [`ptyrun`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/ptyrun.xml). *djbwares*.
- Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). [`ptybandage`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/ptybandage.xml). *djbwares*.
- Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). [`ptyio`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/ptyio.xml). *djbwares*.
- Daniel J. Bernstein (1996). [`ptyget`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/djbwares/guide/commands/ptyget.xml). *djbwares*.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`ptyrun`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ptyrun.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`ptybandage`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ptybandage.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`pty-run`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/pty-run.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`pty-get-tty`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/pty-get-tty.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). [`open-controlling-tty`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/open-controlling-tty.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470853/5132