# Pseudo terminal for comms between two processes

Tags: linux, debian, serial-port, pty, pseudoterminal

I am writing an executable that uses a 3rd party C library ([libmodbus](https://libmodbus.org/) if it matters) to communicate via serial device (in my case, `/dev/ttyUSB0` or similar to talk RS-485 via an FTDI chipset based USB-to-RS485 adapter). This executable, based on CLI args, can initiate commands (in my case, act like a modbus client) then await a response (in my case, from an external modbus server), or listen for incoming commands (in my case, act like a modbus server) then generate a response.

I would like to automate the testing of my executable, without a need for some external device. In other words, I'd like to launch two instances of my executable, where:

- The first instance is put into modbus client mode and uses `/dev/xxxx` for comms
- The second instance is put into modbus server mode and uses `/dev/yyyy` for comms
- Set up `/dev/xxxx` and `/dev/yyyy` to both act as serial devices that are are essentially the two ends of the same wire.

From what I read on [pty manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html), I believe `/dev/xxxx` and `/dev/yyyy` are the two ends of a pseudo-terminal. Which brings me to my questions:

1. The man page refers to BSD-style pseudoterminals which seem more appropriate to what I am trying to do.

   - Is my understanding of BSD-style pseudoterminals correct?
   - If so, is it possible to create BSD-style pseudoterminals on non-BSD linux distributions? In pacticular, I am using debian 10, 11, 12 (and debian based, like Ubuntu 20.04, 22.04)
2. The man page also refers to UNIX 98 pseudoterminals, which are implemented using `posix_openpt()`. However, even after the subsequent `grantpt()` and `unlockpt()`, I can only one one `/dev/pts` device for the client side of the pty, with the master side being only a file descriptor inside the executable.

   - Is my understanding (which is loosely based on [code like this](https://gist.github.com/posborne/7225894)) correct?
   - If so, what tricks may I use to convert the master side file descriptor to an proper `/dev/xxxx` which is the only API available to [get a modbus context](https://libmodbus.org/reference/modbus_new_rtu/)
3. Are there other "standard" linux tools for doing what I am attempting to do? It seems like tools like [the ones mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/561623/352323) are expecting to connect an executable's STDIO to the pty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up PTY "virtual serial ports" using [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

```
socat \
  pty,rawer,echo=0,link=/tmp/portA \
  pty,rawer,echo=0,link=/tmp/portB
```

This will create two PTY devices and two symlinks to those devices. On my system, the above command created:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/port*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 11 Jul 24 11:49 /tmp/portA -> /dev/pts/20
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lars lars 11 Jul 24 11:49 /tmp/portB -> /dev/pts/21
```

You can treat these pty devices as serial ports. For example, I can attach `slcand` to these devices to create CANbus interfaces:

```
slcand -o -c -f -s6 $(readlink /tmp/portA)
slcand -o -c -f -s6 $(readlink /tmp/portB)
```

Or I can attach `picocom` to each port and chat across the virtual link. In one window:

```
picocom $(readlink /tmp/portA)
```

And in another window:

```
picocom $(readlink /tmp/portB)
```

Etc.

---

Both UNIX-98 ptys and BSD-style ptys behave identically; the difference is how they are allocated (UNIX-98 ptys are allocated dynamically while BSD-style ptys are pre-allocated devices).

> However, even after the subsequent grantpt() and unlockpt(), I can only one one /dev/pts device for the client side of the pty, with the master side being only a file descriptor inside the executable.

That's correct; to link two ptys to create a virtual serial line, your code needs to open two pty devices and then handle moving data between the two (that's what `socat` is doing in the above example).

Comment: I needed to modify the socat command slightly (partly for debugging purposes, and partly to make it work for my needs). The final command was 

`socat -x -lu -d -d -d pty,rawer,wait-slave,echo=0,link=/tmp/portA pty,rawer,echo=0,link=/tmp/portB`