# What is the difference between ps -ef | grep WDA and ps -ef | grep [W]DA?

Tags: linux, grep, command

What is the difference between

```
ps -ef | grep WDA
```

and

```
ps -ef | grep [W]DA
```

How exactly `[]` rids of the unwanted info?

Comment: Usual reminder that `pgrep` can likely replace `ps ... | grep ...` and that `pgrep` is clever enough to not match itself.

Answer (score 3):

`WDA` is a regular expression that matches itself.  Thus the output will sometimes include the process listing for the `grep` process.

`[W]DA` is a regular expression that does not match itself.  Thus the output will not include the process listing for the `grep` process.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207363/5132
- Shlomi Noach
  (2009-10-01).  [*How NOT to test that mysqld is alive*](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/how-not-to-test-that-mysqld-is-alive).  code.openark.org.
- Greg Wooledge.  ["The risk of parsing the process tree"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#The_risk_of_parsing_the_process_tree). *Process Management*.  Greg's Wiki.